# How can we create our own Identity Provider?

Tags: javascript, saml-2.0, samlify

I want to implement an identity provider. Is there any npm package to do the same. [Samlify](https://samlify.js.org/#/basic) is on of the library, but documentation ain't good enough fro the same. So, please help me out.

Comment: ive done 1 search and found a list of npm packages that can do the same. please do more research the next time, this site is not made for other people to make your work: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=identity%20provider

Comment: I already did that, but if you take a look then you will find that most of them are just wrapper around the existing IDPs or they use OAuth, but I want to make my own custom IDP.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're hoping to deploy this, but, because of the way it works, SAML processing on the frontend (like in Javascript in the client browser) is insecure. Assertions can certainly be (and typically are) transported by the browser, but the validation of the assertion should be handled server-side.